# How to pass on form inputs and add them to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am wanting to make my website able to add a name and dog breed to an existing list of animals.

```
export const addNewPlayer = async (playerObj) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${APIURL}players/`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: 'Rufus',
          breed: 'Irish Setter',
        }),
      }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

This is the function to create the new player

```
let form = document.querySelector('#new-player-form > form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let playerData = {
      name: form.elements.name.value,
      breed: form.elements.breed.value
    }
    console.log(playerData)

    const players = await fetchAllPlayers()
    renderAllPlayers(players)
    addNewPlayer(playerData);

    renderNewPlayerForm()

  });
```

This is the form that I have here too.

I am just stumped on how to change the "Rufus" and "Irish Setter" to user inputs. When logging the playerData, I can see it running when inspecting, but it only adds the spot for "Rufus".

Some of the code was given, and I am only stumped on the playerObj parameter that was first in the code. I do not see a use, and most of the stuff in addNewPlayer is also given in the API website that was a part of the project. I tried to make the name and breed empty strings but got an error from that.

Comment: running as in seeing inputs in the form that I make and run when submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need is in your `playerData` variable. So, just add the info from it inside your requisiton body. try this:

```
export const addNewPlayer = async (playerObj) => {
//...
body: JSON.stringify({
      name: playerObj.name,
      breed: playerObj.breed,
    }),
```

Comment: Thank you! That ended up working just great. I appreciate the help. Just a question, what does the .name and .breed do in this case, does it take the data from playerData I am assuming?

Comment: Exactly! If you change the key names from your `playerData` with `let playerData = {
      potato: form.elements.name.value,
      tomato: form.elements.breed.value
    }`
your body should now refer to `playerObj.potato` and `playerObj.tomato`